# Create a matrix from multiple matrices in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, join, matrix

I've got a number of matrices, e.g.

Matrix 1:

2 3
4 5

Matrix 2:

7 6
4 1

And so forth...

If I have 4 of these arrays, is there a way that I can assign each array to an element of another array to create one big array, e.g.

Matrix:

2 3 7 6
4 5 4 1
...

I would really appreciate any help in the matter.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try already ? How are stored the matrix in memory ?

Comment: so you want to combine the rows of the matrices?

Answer (score 2):

Let `Mat1,Mat2,Mat3,Mat4` are the **4** given matrices,
Below is the code which will create the desired matrix `Mat5` from the above mentioned **4** matrices,there is no specific logic,you just have to figure out **which element should go where!!**

```
    int Mat1[][]={{2,3},{4,5}};
    int Mat2[][]={{6,7},{8,9}};
    int Mat3[][]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    int Mat4[][]={{5,6},{7,8}};
    int Mat5[][]=new int[4][4];

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {   
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            //inserting first 2 matrices
            Mat5[i][j]=Mat1[i][j];
            Mat5[i][j+2]=Mat2[i][j];
            //inserting last 2 matrices
            Mat5[i+2][j]=Mat3[i][j];
            Mat5[i+2][j+2]=Mat4[i][j];
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

**2 3 6 7

4 5 8 9

1 2 5 6
 
3 4 7 8**

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you want to handle matrices. But I would use vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > mat1(2, std::vector<double>(2)); // 2x2 Matrix
mat1[0][0] = 2;
mat1[0][1] = 3;
mat1[1][0] = 4;
mat1[1][1] = 5;
```

The code above represents your Matrix 1. You could do the same thing for the other matrices. The next step would then be to create the combined matrix:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > combined;

combined.push_back(mat1[0]);
combined.push_back(mat1[1]);
combined.push_back(mat2[0]);
combined.push_back(mat2[1]);
combined.push_back(mat3[0]);
combined.push_back(mat2[1]);
```

The resulting matrix `combined` would look like

```
2 3
4 5
7 6
4 1
```

If you want to be more flexible you could also put all matrices into a vector (i.e., `std::vector > >).

Answer (score 0):

This code requires you to have `Matrix class` of any sort, but is generic and applies to all variants (you can join any amount of matrixes that is perfect square number):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "custom_matrix.hpp"

bool is_perfect_square(long long x)
{
    long long dx=std::sqrt((long double)x);
    if(x==(dx*dx))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> join_matrixes(const std::vector<Matrix<T>>& parts, size_t level)
{
    if(!is_perfect_square(parts.size())) 
        throw; // check if amount of matrixes is correct (1,4,9 etc)
    if(std::sqrt(parts.size()) != level)
        throw; // check if amount of matrixes equals given level of combining
    if(std::find_if(parts.begin(), parts.end(), [&parts](auto x){return !x.is_equal_size(parts.front());}) != parts.end())
        throw; //check if every matrix is equal in size to each other
    Matrix<T> result(level*parts[0].size_x(), level*parts[0].size_y());

    for(Size y = 0; y < level; ++y)
    {
        for(Size x = 0; x < level; ++x)
        {
            for(Size inner_y = 0; inner_y < parts[0].size_y(); ++inner_y )
            {
                for(Size inner_x = 0; inner_x < parts[0].size_x(); ++inner_x )
                {
                    result[y*parts[0].size_y()+inner_y][x*parts[0].size_x()+inner_x] = parts[y*level+x][inner_y][inner_x];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

}

int main()
{

    std::cout << join_matrixes(std::vector<Matrix<float>>
                               {Matrix<float>(3,5,3.14),
                                Matrix<float>(3,5,69.69),
                                Matrix<float>(3,5,13.7),
                                Matrix<float>(3,5,2.71)}, 2) << std::endl;

    std::cout << join_matrixes(std::vector<Matrix<int>>
                               {Matrix<int>(2,2,1),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,4),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,9),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,16),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,25),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,36),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,49),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,64),
                                Matrix<int>(2,2,81)}, 3) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3.140    3.140    3.140    69.690   69.690   69.690
3.140    3.140    3.140    69.690   69.690   69.690
3.140    3.140    3.140    69.690   69.690   69.690
3.140    3.140    3.140    69.690   69.690   69.690
3.140    3.140    3.140    69.690   69.690   69.690
13.700   13.700   13.700   2.710    2.710    2.710
13.700   13.700   13.700   2.710    2.710    2.710
13.700   13.700   13.700   2.710    2.710    2.710
13.700   13.700   13.700   2.710    2.710    2.710
13.700   13.700   13.700   2.710    2.710    2.710

1        1        4        4        9        9
1        1        4        4        9        9
16       16       25       25       36       36
16       16       25       25       36       36
49       49       64       64       81       81
49       49       64       64       81       81
```

You can implement it your way with your matrix class.